# Accessing controller name outside of ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to access the name of a controller when the controller is defined seperate from ng-view?

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <!-- Some code -->
</div>
<div ng-view>
    <!-- Configured with ngRoute -->
</div>
```

Within ng-view I'm able to use $route.current.controller to retrive the current controller name. If possible how would I achieve the same thing for "Ctrl1"?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why would you want to know the controller name?

Comment: I was just trying stuff out and bumped into this problem, it might not be a "real" problem but I thought I'd ask and see if there was a solution.

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant way to know the controller name. BTW, in which context that you need the name, in another controller, some custom directive or in html template of ng-view?

Comment: I have a service called "Debug" where I can call Debug.printCtrlName() based on the service injecting $route. When printCtrlName() is called it will just console.log($route.current.controller). Debug is then injected in all my controllers so I could call printCtrlName in every controller and see when a controller is initiated. But because "Ctrl1" is not handled by $route it ofcourse throws an exception saying $route.current.controller does not exist

Comment: If you just want to know when and which controller is initialized, could you just output it in the controller code, since you will know the name, something like this: app.controller('Ctrl1', function () { console.log('Ctrl1'); })`.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to gather my debug functions in one service and reuse the debug code.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the `ng-view`, **it's possible that there are more than one** `ng-controller` in the same page.

Therefore, it's impossible to have something like `$route.current.controller` to get the current controller.

But if your goal is to just print every controller name that get initialized via `ng-controller`, you could write a custom directive with the same name `ngController`.

```
app.directive('ngController', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.ngController);
    }
  };
});
```

This will output the value inside the `ng-controller` attribute whenever any `ngController` directive has been compiled.

Hope this helps.